# Cross Document Excel Formulas

Tags: excel-formula

Does anybody know if it is possible to `MATCH()` cells across Excel documents?

At the moment I have the following Excel formula which throws a `Value Not Available` error:

```
=MATCH( $C$2, 'fooDoc.csv'!$C$2 : 'fooDoc.csv'!$C$1000, 1 )
```

The idea is that I take the value in cell C2 of the document I am in, and check where it appears in the cell range C2 : C1000 in the fooBar.csv document.

**Please note that the following formula does work, so I do have access to the values:**

```
=MATCH( 'fooDoc.csv'!$C$2, 'fooDoc.csv'!$C$2 : 'fooDoc.csv'!$C$1000, 1 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your formula should look like:

```
=MATCH( $C$2, fooDoc.csv!$C$2:$C$1000, 1 )
```

it works well when the file `fooDoc.csv` is open

btw, the quotes are useless if you have no space in the name of the file